# Using Temporary Security Credentials with the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line

I wanted to generate temporary credentials in AWS CLI, I know the below command should be used.

```
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/role-name --role-session-name "RoleSession1" --profile IAM-user-name > assume-role-output.txt
```

I also have with me access key and secret key with me.

I also ran `aws sts get-caller-identity` and got:

```
{
    "Account": "12345",
    "UserId": "AIXXXXXXXNUNHY",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::12345:user/dcp/ua.166666654"
}
```

But I am not understanding what are the values I should substitute in the above command to get temporary credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `assume-role` will return information similar to:

```
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROAxx:RoleSession1", 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role/role-name"
    }, 
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "xxx", 
        "SessionToken": "xxx", 
        "Expiration": "2018-11-13T07:50:29Z", 
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAxxx"
    }
}
```

Then, run:

```
aws configure --profile RoleSession1
```

and enter the details provided by `assume-role` (Access Key, Secret Key, Token).

This will store new credentials in the `.aws/credentials` file under a `[RoleSession1]` heading.

To use these credentials, specify the profile that you just defined:

```
aws s3 ls --profile RoleSession1
```

Comment: actually i didnt understand wat are the values i need to substitute to call $aws sts assume-role.  the information i have is just access key secret key and the information provided in the question.

Comment: Do you have a role that you wish to assume? Did you try to assume it? What happened?

Comment: i dono wats my role, i am totally new to AWS, i have posted all . the information which i have. using those information is it possible to use this command?

Comment: What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve? For example, why do you wish to assume temporary credentials?

Comment: i am performing a hadoop distcp operation and i need session token for that. without that its throwing an error. since the keys are from 3rd party tool, i am trying to create a temporary credentials

Comment: Why do you need temporary credentials? Can't you just give it normal credentials (Access Key, Secret Key) from an IAM User? If you do so, a Session Token is not required.